# Rascal Charts Broken

Tags: charts, rascal

Rascal has a Charts library, and VSCode just got a recent update with working charts. However, when just applying the code from [the charts library](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/library/vis/charts/), importing of namespaces do not work within either REPL or modules with the Eclipse plugin.

```
rascal>import vis::Charts;
|prompt:///|(0,19,<1,0>,<1,19>): Could not import module vis::Charts: can not find in search path
```

A comparable set of code within a module results into the following error:

```
public void drawPieChart(map[str, int] code, str label){
    pieChart(toRel(code));
}
```

Which is nothing more than an analysed program with classes and their respective LOC.

The results of calling that function:

```
rascal>readTest();
Reloading module Test
The total lines in this project: 17507
|project://*********/src/Visualize.rsc|(968,8,<35,1>,<35,9>): Undeclared variable: pieChart
Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/UndeclaredVariable/UndeclaredVariable.html|
```

I tried importing charts from vis::Charts via the console (in the right project), tried it within a module and updated to version 0.26.7. Still no dice and broken Charts namespace.

There are problems with the figure library (judging by the amount of figure-library tags) in the issue tracker on GitHub, but I wasn't aware that it was removed completely, nor was it in any way clear that it was not functional on the documentation page. What am I doing wrong? If I am not doing anything wrong, when is it expected to be fixed?

Comment: We did not release the new eclipse plugin yet; so you are looking at new documentation of vis::Charts that works in VScode, but has not been released for Eclipse yet.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen, fast as always. When is it expected to be released?

Comment: I'm trying to do it today, but I can't promise anything. So much to do, so little time. See my  release/testing progress here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1735